# Unable to find the origin of " __ar_v4" cookie in asp.net mvc website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

On production of 2 of our websites built using .NET 4 ASP.NET MVC. There is this particular cookie named "__ar_v4" created, with a very high expiry date.

I tried searching that cookie name and about its origin in my code, but could not find it.

If my website is www.test.com, my auth cookie is set of this same domain, but this particular cookie is set of ".www.test.com" (notice the .) and same goes for the other website.

I want to remove that, and find the origin of it, is it created by the .net framework ? Could not get any leads on the web. Please help.

Comment: Seems to be related to ads. (AdRoll?)

Comment: @SaebAmini how can i confirm this ? The site is very old, and I have not idea about "AdRoll" being used anywhere. Where can i find the reference and remove it ?

Comment: I'm not sure, you'll have to figure that out yourself. But a [quick](https://www.distilled.net/cookie-policy/) Google [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=__ar_v4&oq=__ar_v4&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) makes it almost [certain](http://www.bristolairport.co.uk/cookie-policy) that it's related to advertisement and AdRoll.

Comment: @SaebAmini thanks a lot, would have definitely wasted a day on it. Since the code base is very old, someone might have added the adroll script and have forgotten. Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome :) so you found it?

Comment: This cookie also appears if you log in to Confluence by Atlassian, so not .net. They use a java backend - tomcat probably.

Answer (score 0):

This cookie is set and used by [Adroll](https://www.adroll.com/).